# Android 11 set IP-address of device usb tethering

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am using pi 4 running android 11 for my project, and i have 1 android app to start server via usb tethering but every time start it gives another ipaddress, is there any way i can set default ipaddress so that every time you start, your ip won't change, and this device I can root the device
Thanks all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.